# How make $resource wait more timeout than 30s?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

Conbsider the code:

```
var searchResource = function(token) {
    var _url = ['my_url', '/somePAth'].join('');
    return $resource(_url, {}, {
        query: {
            timeout: 300000,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Auth: 'my_token'
            }
        }
    });
};
```

When I user `timeout: 10` I got timeout exception immidiatelly but when I set it to `300000` any responce ends up with 30s (not 300s). It there another settings for timeout, say maxTimeout for all angularjs resources? How to make $resource wait more time than 30s?

Browser is GoogleChrome 65.0.3325.181

Angularjs version 1.5.11

Comment: Isn't the 30 second timeout on the server?  If it is then you won't be able to change it this way.  That said, if I thought I had to set a timeout to something so high I'd stop what I was doing and rethink it.

Comment: Maybe your server timeouts after 30s and not js?

Comment: try this `timeout: 0` hope this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on backend, not at angular side. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#timeoutInMillis)

Many thanks for comments about backend.